# How to set LE discoverable flag for ibeacon packet inside beacon class of android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ads

I am using the beacon class (`altbeacon.beacon.Beacon`) which makes it possible to create an **ibeacon** advertisement packet.

However the packet differs in the first 3 bytes (advertisement flags, which should be 0x020106 according to the ibeacon standard, containing the flag 0x06 which stands for "LE general discoverable").

I did not find a way to set those bytes from within the beacon library. Is there a way to the set those flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library's BeaconTransmitter class is based on Android's native BluetoothLeAdvertiser:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html

Unfortunately, that class provides no ability to configure the specific flags set in the advertising packet.  As a result, you are left with the defaults you have seen.